# How to write data to a two-dimensional array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

The question is that I receive data via a websocket and I need to write it to a two-dimensional array. How to do it?

```
myWs.onmessage = function (message) {
    const jsonParse = JSON.parse(message.data);    
    try {  
        
        for (let i = 0; i < mockLineData.length; i++) {         
          mockLineData[i].data[i].y = jsonParse[i]['value_state'];
          mockLineData[i].data[i].x = inc;
          console.log(mockLineData[i].data[i].y);               
        }     
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    }
};


export const mockLineData = [
  {
    id: "ИБП Uвх",
    color: tokens("dark").redAccent[200],
    data: [
      {
        x: 0, 
        y: 1,
      },
      
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Can you give more Information? What is the data you receive? How is it currently interpreted and how do you want it to be interpreted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can iterate two dimensional array by using **map()**

```
const token = tokens("dark").redAccent[200]

const mockLineData = [
  {
    id: "ИБП Uвх",
    color: token,
    data: [
      {
        x: 0, 
        y: 1,
      },
      
    ],
  },
];

 mockLineData.forEach((item) => {
    item.data.forEach((dataItem) => {
        console.log(item.id, item.color, dataItem.x, dataItem.y)
    })
})
```

Comment: Don't use `map` when you ignore the return value. Use `forEach` instead.